# Elegant conversion of tab separated log lines into a CSV matrix

Tags: python, csv, converters

I have a tab-separated log file with lines like that:

```
event_a info1 info2
event_b info1 info4
event_c info2 info5 ...
```

I want to convert this into a csv (with Python) where a column has a meaning. info1 e.g. is an ID, info2 is a desintation, info4 is a coordinate etc.

I can easily do this the "sloppy" way:

```
if "event_a" in line:
   columns = line.split()
   id = columns[1]
```

I would prefer to have something like a lookup matrix or table structure for this, so that the positions for the columns are separated from the programming logic. Is there something which allows me to define an expressive overview here, so that I could code like:

```
for line in csvfile:
    matches = event_table.match(line)
    for match in matches:
       event_table.convert(match) 
       # add commas in between the values to account for empty columns
```

I could of course create a class per event, but that seems to be overkill. What I am looking for is a central definition, which I can use.

The output is:

```
 event_a, info1 info2
 event_b, info1, , , info4
 event_b, , info2, , , info5
 ...
 event_365, , , , , , , , , , , , info12
```

edit: the log file contains 100s of such event types, which would make this code rather long and hard to maintain doing this the "waterfall"-parsing way

Comment: why don't you split it all in a list?

Comment: If you want to go the overdesigned route, then `pyparsing` might be your cup of tea..

Comment: Show expected output.

Comment: I edited the question. As the title suggests I am not looking for a quick way but for a way to keep the logic as separate from the code as possible. E.g. I can give the column definition to somebody else to take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you could split the line first, and then use cell[0] to access the lookup table

here's one way to do it, although i feel like i'm playing code golf.

```
lines = ['fooevent\tfoo_info1\tfoo_info2',
     'barevent\tbar_info2\tbar_info4',
     'basevent\tbas_info2\tbas_info5'
     ]

mapper = {
    'fooevent':(1,2),
    'barevent':(2,4),
    'basevent':(2,5)
}

output_length = max([max(v) for v in mapper.values()]) + 1

a = lambda x,m: fields[1:][m.index(x)] if x in m else ''

for line in lines:

    fields = line.split('\t')
    data = [a(x,mapper[fields[0]]) for x in range(1,output_length)]
    data.insert(0,fields[0])
    print(','.join(data))
```

it might be easier to use a hash for the individual mappers than tuples, if only because they're easier to map to other data types later if you your map table gets more complicated.